# Converting (Casting) column to make operations in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's what i'm having trouble with. I have a table where i have the column weight, the data in this column is varchar2, example: 60 kg.

When i try to make a WHERE condition asking to retrieve everything below 60 kg, it doesn't give me the wanted results.

I tried to convert using to_number but it's not working and giving me error "Invalid Number". I also tried to cut the kg with SUBSTR and convert, and doesn't work as well.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show additional examples of the values.

Comment: Edited adding a picture with some information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract leading digits and convert that to a number:

```
select to_number(regexp_substr(weight, '^[0-9]*'))
from t;
```

The regular expression is starting from the beginning of the string (the `^`) and extracting digits.  The `*` is for any number of digits.  Regular expression match is "greedy" by default, meaning that it will keep matching as many digits in a row as there are.

If you have decimal places or negative values, this might be a tad bit more complicated.

Comment: This works. I haven't studied the regexp yet, basically this together with the substr is cutting only numbers from whatever is in the column, right? i will search for the regexp and read about it. And thankfully i'm only working with round numbers this time.

Thank you very much for answering my question.